# Pass multiple values/observables to custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm doing a simple custom binding which accepts a plain observable and adds the value of the observable to the bound element's css class list,  like so:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="cssClassBinding: state">
</div>

ko.bindingHandlers.cssClassBinding = {//simplified example code
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).addClass(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    },
}
```

What I'm trying to do is be able to bind multiple values with this binding.  I tried just putting another binding with a different value, but KO only evaluates one instance per element apparently.

```
//won't work
<div class="container" data-bind="cssClassBinding: state, cssClassBinding: type">
</div>
```

So I'm trying to see if I can do it more like this:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="cssClassBinding: {state, type}">
</div>

ko.bindingHandlers.cssClassBinding = {//simplified example code
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        foreach (observableValue in iDon'tKnowWhere)
            $(element).addClass(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(observableValue));
    },
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I found is just to handle the binding an array of observables, like so:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="cssClassBinding: [state, type]">
</div>
```

And just write the custom binding to check if it's an array or not.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that please?

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way to bind multiple observables is creating an object within the binding:

```
<div data-bind="exampleBinding: { State: state, Type: type }"></div>
```

Then the custom binding would access those properties through the valueAccessor (this assumes state and value are knockout observables on the view model):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.exampleBinding = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        // read properties
        console.log(value.State());
        console.log(value.Type());
        // update properties
        value.State('test1');
        value.Type('test2');
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying for days to do this now, driving me nuts.
My data-bind is like so : data-bind="htmlEditor: {note: model.note, state: model.state}"

In my view model ive set up the following  -
self.note = ko.observable(params.model.note());
                self.state = ko.observable(params.model.planState());
the above returns the values Im looking for so I dont think the issue is there.

Comment: My init ive tried many ways to no avail -
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var modelProperty = valueAccessor(),
                //propertyValue = ko.unwrap(modelProperty.note());
            propertyValue = ko.unwrap(modelProperty);
            //var stateProperty = valueAccessor(),
            //stateValue = ko.unwrap(modelProperty.state());
            alert("val = " + propertyValue);
            //alert("state = " + stateValue);
What the hell am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TerryDelahunt Terry, you may want to add your example at jsfiddle.net to see what's going on here.  In your comments, it looks like your markup is binding to model.note (for this to work your view model would need an object with the name "model", which then includes note and state properties).  It appears your view model just has note and state properties at the root level though (not nested under an object named model).